# ¿Por qué se usa pronombre indirecto de objetos cuando existe el objeto indirecto?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

Por ejemplo en este frase:

> Jenny le está escribiendo una carta a su padre

¿Por qué se necesita "le" cuando el objeto indirecto (su padre) es tan obvio?

Comment: Su padre es objeto *indirecto* (el objeto directo es *una carta*). La duplicación del objeto directo es normal (y a veces, aunque no en tu ejemplo, obligatoria)

Comment: perdóname! ya he corregido la pregunta. ¿por qué se usa "le"? todavía no entiendo. ¿se cambiaría el sentimiento si solo escibiera: "Jenny está escribiendo una carta a su padre"?

Comment: significaría lo mismo (se puede escribir o no). Si fuese *a él* o si *a su padre* viniera antes del verbo, sería obligatorio usar *le*.

Comment: perdóname otra vez... ya existe muchas respuestas acá https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/what-is-the-role-of-the-le-in-the-sentence-miguel-le-dio-a-su-novia-un-anillo. pero gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Bueno, aunque hay respuestas, la aceptada allí es incorrecta.

Comment: jaja me parece que sería más fácil de siempre agregar el pronombre y nunca preguntar, ¿por qué?

Comment: @guifa marqué como duplicado de la pregunta [¿Es correcto “pegarle a un padre”? Y en general, ¿se puede repetir el complemento indirecto en una frase usando “le” o “se” además del explícito?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20199/1674) donde [tu respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20200/1674) detalla esto.

Comment: @fedorqui olividóseme de aquella respuesta haga, voy a retocarla y profundizarla si me da tiempo con algunos ejemplos

Comment: Creo que la siguiente respuesta te podrá ayudar: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20539/9385